# Invoke a subclass method from arraylist

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, subclass, superclass

I have a subclass called dvdToRent and inside the class there is a method called dvdRental which i want to call directly from an arrayList called dvdCompany

```
public void dvdRental (int dvdNumber, String customer)
{         

    if (dvds.size() < 0) {
       System.out.println("Empty list");
       }
       else if (dvdNumber >= dvds.size()) {
           System.out.println("Doesn't exist!!");
        }
    else {

        dvd  = dvds.get(dvdNumber);
        dvdToRent.dvdrental(customer);
    } 
}
```

Thats what i was thinking probably it could call the method but it does not, it is giving me an error in the last line. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We'll need to see more code. And probably the error message.

Comment: Are you looking more like a Reflection-type invocation of method on the class?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a method directly from a List because a List is a collection of objects. You have to choose one specific element of this collection.

For example like that:

```
dvdToRent.get(0).dvdrental(customer);
```

This takes the first element out of the List called dvdToRent and then uses this element to call dvdrental with the parameter customer.

Comment: I am trying to get the dvd number from the user so it applies to that particular dvd in the second last line. After getting the dvd number , I want it to invoke the method so it rents it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `dvd` is declared as `dvdToRent`, it looks like you want your last line to be

```
dvd.dvdrental(customer);
```

instead of

```
dvdToRent.dvdrental(customer);
```